# How to set maxDate and minDate with jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have date range below example and I want to set minimum date for my `#checkout` input. after selected a days from my `#checkin`.`#checkout` search date can't be more than 15 days for date range that is why I want to prevent it

```js
$(function() {

  var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY",
    from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      minDate: 0,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

        window.setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
          $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find("#checkout,.checkout").focus();
        }, this), 10);
        var yenitarih = new Date();
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

        $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
      },
      isTo1: true,
    }).on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
      firstDay: 1,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      minDate: 0,
      maxDate: +15,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $(this).parents(".book-holiday").find(".popover-wrapper").addClass("open");
        $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
      },
    }).on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });


});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="book-holiday">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" />
  <input type="text" id="checkout" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: thanks.. I can't use different plugin we have jquery ui.

Comment: So basically your #checkout date should be 15 days after from #checkin date. is it?

Comment: yes exactly @MayankPatel

Comment: Your code is working for only month of July.Right?

Comment: yes exactly.my code is not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Moment.js for all the calculations regarding date stuff.

I have used `onSelect` event of `#checkin` and set the minDate and maxDate of `#checkout` date picker.

So whatever will be `#checkin` date `#checkout` will be 15 days after it.

Below is the Fiddle you can check.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/75n5k91h/5/)

**EDIT**

Please check below fiddle I dont have used Moment.js

[Without Moment Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75n5k91h/7/)

Comment: Hey @Mayank thank you..moment.js is a big fs file can't we do without moment.js ?

Comment: It is lightweight. This will be helpful for most of your stuff related to Date.It won't affect performance.You just need to include 1 cdn js of moment.js

Comment: By the way I am working on it without usin Moment.js

Comment: Please check Edit in My answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. It should work.
You only need to create function daysBetween():

```
$(function() {
  // Const with max days diff
  var MAX_DAYS_DIFFERENCE = 15;
  // your start date -- Date instance. Paste your date
  // your end date -- Date instance. Paste your date
  var startDate = new Date().format('yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss');
  var endDate = new Date().format('yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss');

  var dateFormat = "DD/MM/YY";
  var from = $("#checkin,.checkin").datepicker({
      // You can set date format
      dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss',
      maxDate: endDate,
      // Your code
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      firstDay: 1,
      onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

        startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
        // we compute the day difference and remove the maximum allowed date difference to find
        // how many days are above the difference and then we remove/add those days
        const daysDiff = daysBetween(startDate, endDate) - MAX_DAYS_DIFFERENCE;
        if (daysDiff > 0) {
          endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - daysDiff);
          to.datepicker('setDate', endDate);
        }
      },
      isTo1: true,
  });

  from.datepicker('setDate', startDate);

  var to = $("#checkout,.checkout").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss',
    minDate: startDate,
    maxDate: new Date() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 1000 * 1000,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      endDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      from.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDate);
      // we compute the day difference and remove the maximum allowed date difference to find
      // how many days are above the difference and then we remove/add those days
      var daysDiff = daysBetween(startDate, endDate) - MAX_DAYS_DIFFERENCE;
      if (daysDiff > 0) {
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + daysDiff);
        from.datepicker('setDate', startDate);
      }
    },
  });
  to.datepicker('setDate', endDate);
});
```

Comment: hey thank you it gave me a error : `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).format is not a function` https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/PjEwVO